# How pass data to a form inside jquery UI dialog modal windows?

Tags: jquery-ui, forms, modal-dialog

I'm trying to use the jquery UI dialog component to display a form; which I successfully did.

However I'm at lost on how to retrieve data to this form inside the dialog window. Is it possible? The example shown on jquery website only shows static messages.

Comment: If the form is not a separate page or iframe, what's the problem with giving it any data?

Comment: I ran into a similar problem, using ajaxform inside the modal dialog just don't work and submit the form as if there was no ajaxform implemented. I challenged my ajaxform without this modalbox and it works fine. If you finally found a solution I'll take it ! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can tell us more about the problem. What data do you want do display and in which format is this data (is it form data, javascript objects, dom objects, etc.?)

You talked about a form which is shown via a dialog. Where do you want to access this form data (when the dialog is closed, opened, when the form is submitted, ...)?